# Como graficar una tabla con seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

estoy cargando un archivo CSV para graficarlo usando seaborn, el código a continuación no me genera error alguno pero no me está generando el gráfico, será que me falta agregar algo ?

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

datos = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')
nuevo = datos[["Genre","Global_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales"]]
g = sns.pairplot(nuevo, hue="Genre", palette="Spectral")
```

al imprimir la variable nuevo si me carga todo el contenido del csv (para verificar que si carga el documento correctamente) adjunto imagen del archivo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Rank,Name,Platform,Year,Genre,Publisher,NA_Sales,EU_Sales,JP_Sales,Other_Sales,Global_Sales
1,Wii Sports,Wii,2006,Sports,Nintendo,41.49,29.02,3.77,8.46,82.74
2,Super Mario Bros.,NES,1985,Platform,Nintendo,29.08,3.58,6.81,0.77,40.24
3,Mario Kart Wii,Wii,2008,Racing,Nintendo,15.85,12.88,3.79,3.31,35.82
4,Wii Sports Resort,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,15.75,11.01,3.28,2.96,33
5,Pokemon Red/Pokemon Blue,GB,1996,Role-Playing,Nintendo,11.27,8.89,10.22,1,31.37
6,Tetris,GB,1989,Puzzle,Nintendo,23.2,2.26,4.22,0.58,30.26
7,New Super Mario Bros.,DS,2006,Platform,Nintendo,11.38,9.23,6.5,2.9,30.01
8,Wii Play,Wii,2006,Misc,Nintendo,14.03,9.2,2.93,2.85,29.02
9,New Super Mario Bros. Wii,Wii,2009,Platform,Nintendo,14.59,7.06,4.7,2.26,28.62
10,Duck Hunt,NES,1984,Shooter,Nintendo,26.93,0.63,0.28,0.47,28.31
11,Nintendogs,DS,2005,Simulation,Nintendo,9.07,11,1.93,2.75,24.76
12,Mario Kart DS,DS,2005,Racing,Nintendo,9.81,7.57,4.13,1.92,23.42
13,Pokemon Gold/Pokemon Silver,GB,1999,Role-Playing,Nintendo,9,6.18,7.2,0.71,23.1
14,Wii Fit,Wii,2007,Sports,Nintendo,8.94,8.03,3.6,2.15,22.72
15,Wii Fit Plus,Wii,2009,Sports,Nintendo,9.09,8.59,2.53,1.79,22
16,Kinect Adventures!,X360,2010,Misc,Microsoft Game Studios,14.97,4.94,0.24,1.67,21.82
17,Grand Theft Auto V,PS3,2013,Action,Take-Two Interactive,7.01,9.27,0.97,4.14,21.4
18,Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas,PS2,2004,Action,Take-Two Interactive,9.43,0.4,0.41,10.57,20.81
19,Super Mario World,SNES,1990,Platform,Nintendo,12.78,3.75,3.54,0.55,20.61
20,Brain Age: Train Your Brain in Minutes a Day,DS,2005,Misc,Nintendo,4.75,9.26,4.16,2.05,20.22
21,Pokemon Diamond/Pokemon Pearl,DS,2006,Role-Playing,Nintendo,6.42,4.52,6.04,1.37,18.36
22,Super Mario Land,GB,1989,Platform,Nintendo,10.83,2.71,4.18,0.42,18.14
23,Super Mario Bros. 3,NES,1988,Platform,Nintendo,9.54,3.44,3.84,0.46,17.28
24,Grand Theft Auto V,X360,2013,Action,Take-Two Interactive,9.63,5.31,0.06,1.38,16.38
25,Grand Theft Auto: Vice City,PS2,2002,Action,Take-Two Interactive,8.41,5.49,0.47,1.78,16.15
26,Pokemon Ruby/Pokemon Sapphire,GBA,2002,Role-Playing,Nintendo,6.06,3.9,5.38,0.5,15.85
27,Pokemon Black/Pokemon White,DS,2010,Role-Playing,Nintendo,5.57,3.28,5.65,0.82,15.32
28,Brain Age 2: More Training in Minutes a Day,DS,2005,Puzzle,Nintendo,3.44,5.36,5.32,1.18,15.3
29,Gran Turismo 3: A-Spec,PS2,2001,Racing,Sony Computer Entertainment,6.85,5.09,1.87,1.16,14.98
30,Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3,X360,2011,Shooter,Activision,9.03,4.28,0.13,1.32,14.76
31,Pokémon Yellow: Special Pikachu Edition,GB,1998,Role-Playing,Nintendo,5.89,5.04,3.12,0.59,14.64
32,Call of Duty: Black Ops,X360,2010,Shooter,Activision,9.67,3.73,0.11,1.13,14.64
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega las filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, no como imagen, de esa forma podemos copiar y pegar para hacer pruebas. En general, toda la información en las preguntas debería ir en texto para que otros usuarios puedan reproducir el error e intentar darle solución. Las imágenes sirven para mostrar el resultado esperado, por ejemplo, ¿Cómo se ve la gráfica que estás creando actualmente? o ¿Cómo esperarías que se viera?. De esa forma podemos trabajar inmediatamente en tu problema sin necesidad de solicitar información por los comentarios. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo único que hace falta es mostrar el gráfico, para eso debes utilizar `pyplot` de `matplotlib`

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datos = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')
nuevo = datos[["Genre","Global_Sales","JP_Sales","EU_Sales"]]
g = sns.pairplot(nuevo, hue="Genre", palette="Spectral")

plt.show()
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

**Edición:** En algunas versiones de matplotlib, en combinación con el sistema operativo y el IDE, las gráficas se cierran inmediatamente al terminar de ejecutar el script, `matplotlib` ha creado un argumento opcional en el método `show` para evitar que se cierre la gráfica en dichos casos

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

Por lo que estuve leyendo en los reportes de errores el problema parece estar relacionado con Mac (Esto último no ha sido 100% verificado ya que no encontré ningún reporte de Windows o Linux)

Comment: hola saludo cordial, yo hice eso pero muestra un "flash" en la pantalla e inmediatamente se borra la imagen (estoy usando vs code)

Comment: ¿Has revisado la configuración de VS Code? Lo acabo de ejecutar ahí y tal como está el programa funciona correctamente y me muestra la gráfica, también lo probe en la terminal y en JupyterLab

Comment: Donde puedo revisar esa configuración del visual studio code ?

Comment: Oprime `Ctrl`, `Shift` y `P` al mismo tiempo y escribe "terminal settings", selecciona la única opción que aparece y abrirá una nueva ventana, luego escribe esto en el buscador `@feature:terminal integrated inherit` y revisa que la opción que aparece tenga el checkbox seleccionado. También revisa la versión de `matplotlib` que estas utilizando, tal vez hace falta que lo actualices `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

Comment: ¿Ya instalaste el debugger de python para VS Code?

Comment: el lo muestra (la ventana e inmediatamente la oculta) voy a probar tus indicaciones y te contaré como me va . gracias

Comment: Intenta con esto `plt.show(block=True)` ¿Estás utilizando Mac?

Comment: La ultima instrucción solucionó el problema. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y ayudarme con mi problema

Comment: No hay de que, agregué una explicación en la respuesta para que otros usuarios no tengan que leer todos los comentarios. Saludos